# Cropping Image by user selecting image from gallery

Tags: android, image, image-processing

I am creating an application in android in which I want to let the user select his profile pic from a photo gallery. I want to let the user crop an image for his profile picture when selecting the image from the gallery, or capturing an image from the camera. I am using the image chooser library for capturing or choosing an image from library. Can anyone suggest what would be the best way to implement this?

Comment: There are many [image cropping libraries for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45).

Answer (score 0):

First You can use this code to take image from galley and with camera :
It Surely works:

```
        private void selectImage() {
    final CharSequence[] items = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Library", "Cancel" };
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Enrolement.this);
    builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
            } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),
                        SELECT_FILE);
            } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
            onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
        else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
            onCaptureImageResult(data);
    }
}

private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
    Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

    File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

    FileOutputStream fo;
    try {
        destination.createNewFile();
        fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ivImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {
    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(selectedImageUri, projection, null, null,
            null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    String selectedImagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);

    Bitmap bm;
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);
    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 200;
    int scale = 1;
    while (options.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE
            && options.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
        scale *= 2;
    options.inSampleSize = scale;
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);

    ivImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
}
```

Main Part is cropping : 
U can call startActivity() on an Intent with an action of                                          **com.android.camera.action.CROP**

```
       Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");  
  intent.setClassName("com.android.camera", "com.android.camera.CropImage");  
 File file = new File(filePath);  
 Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);  
intent.setData(uri);  
intent.putExtra("crop", "true");  
 intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);  
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);  
intent.putExtra("outputX", 96);  
 intent.putExtra("outputY", 96);  
  intent.putExtra("noFaceDetection", true);  
 intent.putExtra("return-data", true);                                  
 startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CROP_ICON);
```

When the picture select Activity return will be selected to save the contents.in onActivityResult:

```
          Bundle extras = data.getExtras();  
        if(extras != null ) {  
          Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");  
           ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
            photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, stream);  
          / / The stream to write to a file or directly using the
             }
```

It might work , but this is not a good practice to use **com.android.camera.action.CROP**
as android doesn't have a Crop intent.

Comment: Thanks, but i am using image chooser library so can you tell me that when i am picking an image from library so then what sh'd i do for giving cropping functionalities to user

Comment: If u r using your Library means gallery or File Manger but not camera thn simply delete the camera thing from the code and after picking image u can use same action com.android.camera.action.CROP @Gaurav Setia